# Running Python Script from outside of Python Error: DLL load failed while importing etree: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was using Python IDLE to create my codes, created an environment variable to run the code from run window outside of idle and it was working fine. Recently I downloaded Anaconda for a class and when I try to run a code from outside of idle I get the below message error. Is there a way to change the directory which python is looking for packages to a different path as I assume once I downloaded Anaconda the path has changed. I appreciate you help.

Here is my traceback

```
  File "C:\Users\h.omail\MyPythonScripts\RFQs.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, os.path, docx, win32com.client, shutil, send2trash, PyPDF2, textract, re, pprint
  File "C:\Users\h.omail\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from docx.api import Document  # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-docx
```

OR

```
pip3 install python-docx
```

Comment: Thank you, but all the packages are installed already it is just that windows is looking for them in Anaconda folder instead of python 3.8 folder I need to change the directory of looking to packages to python 3.8